# Где взять датасет спутниковых снимков в виде изображений?

Tags: машинное-обучение, dataset

Месяц уже как ищу датасет изображений спутниковых снимков. 
Для обучения распознавания ландшафтных объектов с помощью нейросети.

Полно информации о том, КАК это сделать. Но не могу найти тренировочный датасет не в виде CSV, а в виде изображений. Уже отчаялся.

Находил на [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ceperaang/lb-0-42-ultimate-full-solution-run-on-your-hw?select=sixteen_band.zip) 20Гб датасет с TIFF изображениями для соревнований, но внутри TIFF файлов не было **ничего**. Файлы открывались. Занимали много места, но вместо изображений - пустота. :((

Также нашел данные со спутника [Landsat](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), но все, что удалось скачать - это CSV файл. 
В котором хранятся такие данные: 
[image: Скрин распакованных данных]
Что с ними делать - я так и не понял.
Поэтому ищу изображения.

Надеюсь на помощь сообщества.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sentinel Hub](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/sentinel-playground) Ура! Ура! Ура! Нашел!
Качество изображений не самое лучшее, зато собрать данные таким образом гораздо проще. Да и для распознавания и так пойдет.

Comment: На Kaggle был нормальный датасет. Просто я не тем местом смотрел, когда читал в описании строчку, что GeoTIFF не открывается стандартными программами...